# jsoup is not resolved on googles app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsoup

Hi I'm new to googles app engine. 
I'm trying to use a library Jsoup on google app engine. I have insert the app jre in the WEB-INF/lib/ folder, but when I try to use it i get the error Jsoup can't be resolved.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");
```

Any suggestions on how to add the library in app engine and use it?
Thanks

Comment: Have you added jars to Build Path?

Comment: thanks for the answer adding them to the path seams to work